# Add an attribute to many tables automatically

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench

I have a database diagram in Workbench and this diagram is synchronized with my database. This database has more than 500 tables, and I need to add a new column to most tables, it is not a viable option to add it one by one and then synchronize the changes with the database. Is there any workbench option that allows me to add the field in bulk to many tables ?.

The only way I can think of is to make a script that automatically adds that attribute to the tables and then perform the inverse synchronization, that is, update the diagram from the database.

What do you think? Any better solution?

Comment: "This database has more than 500 tables, and I need to add a new attribute to most tables" with new attribute you mean column?

Comment: yes, I'm sorry.

Comment: Willing to add a column to almost 500 tables sounds like you have a bad database design with alot of the same tables?

Comment: There are many tables because they have used EAV. Obviously I will not add it in all the tables. Is there a way to automate the process? that is, I can select the tables where the attribute should be created.

Comment: EAV and EAV/CR means that you several (5-15) tables including metadata ones that store all data. 500 tables means that you extract EAV data to relational model to make queries work in an acceptable time.

Comment: Alright, but this is a previous design that I have to maintain. It is not up to critics right now, since I am not asking wether it is good or bad, it is already done, will not be changed, but I need to perform the task I mentioned previously. Thank you

Comment: It is possible to create all 500 ALTERs in one SQL statement.  Then copy & paste to execute.  Do you want that?

Comment: of course not. Read my question I want to know if there is any option in Workbench that allows to add that to the diagram to later synchronize it with the database.